# Replacing the 0 from 1000.00 but not the 0 from inputed value of custom keypad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am trying to make a project that has quick cash button of 500.00 and 1000.00. im trying to slice or replace the 0 whenever i press my keypad. for example i choose 1000.00 then followed by 2,0,8 from my keypad, the expected output should be 1002.08. everytime i press 0 then followed by another number. its just changing the 0 from my keypad

i tried replace(/[^.1-9]/), slice(0, noneZeroIndex) + value

here's my current code for handling keypad

```
const handleKeypadButton = useCallback(
    (value: string) => {
      if (value === 'C') {
        setIsQuickCash(false);
        setSelectedValues('');
      } else if (value === '.') {
        setSelectedValues((prevSelectedValues: string) => {
          const stringValue = prevSelectedValues?.toString();
          if (!stringValue?.includes('.')) {
            return stringValue + value;
          }
          return stringValue;
        });
      } else if (isQuickCash) {
        setSelectedValues((prevSelectedValues: string) => {
          const stringValue = prevSelectedValues?.toString();
          const nonZeroIndex = stringValue?.lastIndexOf('0');
          if (stringValue === '0') {
            return value;
          } else {
            if (nonZeroIndex === -1) {
              const decimalIndex = stringValue?.indexOf('.');
              const updatedValue = insertAtIndexOfDecimal(
                stringValue,
                value,
                decimalIndex,
              );
              return updatedValue;
            } else {
              console.log(nonZeroIndex);
              const newValue =
                stringValue.slice(0, nonZeroIndex) +
                value +
                stringValue.slice(nonZeroIndex + 1);

              return newValue;
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        const newValue = selectedValues + value;
        setSelectedValues(newValue);
      }
    },
    [isQuickCash, selectedValues],
  );
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your issue?

Comment: i've tried changing the lastIndexOf of nonZeroIndex to indexOf. it gives me the output i want except when pressing 0. it still changes the inputed 0. i also tried slicing from the last index of 0 but it slices even the decimal. i've been searching if there is a way to exempt the decimal from slicing thats why i came up with regex replace that exempts the decimal.